# Error executing command during installation of Node.js and npm on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, nodejs, curl, npm

I have been trying to install `Node.js` and the related package `npm` on my `Ubuntu 19.04`.
I have: `v10.15.2` for `Node.js` and `5.8.0' for`npm`.

I know from [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58648010/npm-5-8-0-does-not-support-node-js-v10-15-2-on-ubuntu-19-04/58648162?noredirect=1#comment103601620_58648162) that the default version of `npm` for `Node 10.15.2` is `6.4.1`.
However when I try both to `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` I am not able to upgrade `npm` to the requested version.

The error I am getting is below:

[image: error]

I have been doing a lot of research and I have tried to install in different ways:

1) I removed and reinstalled both `Node.js` and `npm` but nothing seems to change

2) after `sudo apt update` I have the following output:

[image: update]

3) I followed the [following source](https://fosslovers.com/install-npm-in-ubuntu-18-04/), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650300/npm-update-check-failed) and also [this additional source](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-19-04.html)

4) After an additional time I also went on the [official website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and accessed to the [download page](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and chose the option for "Installing Node.js via package manager" and went to the related options and accessed to the [binary distributions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md) and followed the command line advised command:

a) Using Ubuntu
`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -`
`sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

I am running out of ideas and I am not sure on how to proceed from this point. anyone who could be of any guidance would be greatly appreciate to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you on 19.10 or 19.04 or 17.10 or 16.04?  You have a ***lot*** of mixed sources here that suggest your system is not in a stable state that could be causing issues.  You also have a repository that is not supporting Disco (19.04), and is erroring so you have to remove the ros repository from your sources.

Comment: @ThomasWard, thanks for reading the question. I am on `Ubuntu 19-04`. `Ubuntu-19.04` does not allow to install ROS Melodic and in fact I am trying to install it from source. I hope this could help you understand what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error that refers to [`ros.org`](https://www.ros.org/), which is about robot software. That is, it is unrelated to nodejs.

The exact error is that this repository does not have a `disco` release (Ubuntu 19.10) for the ROS software. You can verify that there is not *disco* software by visiting the repository's page at http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/.

You can disable this repository by running

```
software-properties-gtk
```

Then, visit the tab *Other Software* and find the ROS entry. 
Finally, unlesect the ROS entry and click to Save.

Comment: Fantastic!!!! That solved the problem! :) thank you very much!